# Possible to upgrade jboss 5.1 jpa1 to jpa 2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss5.x

Is it possible to upgrade Hibernate/JPA that is shipped with JBoss 5.1 to use JPA 2.0?  I am interested in making use of the OrderColumn.

I am unable to upgrade JBoss to the latest version - 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to upgrade Hibernate/JPA that is shipped with JBoss 5.1 to use JPA 2.0?

No.

> I am interested in making use of the OrderColumn.

Hibernate has an [`@IndexColumn`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/IndexColumn.html) equivalent.

> #### 2.4.6.2.1. List
>
> Beyond EJB3, Hibernate Annotations
>   supports true `List` and `Array`. Map
>   your collection the same way as usual
>   and add the `@IndexColumn`. This
>   annotation allows you to describe the
>   column that will hold the index. You
>   can also declare the index value in DB
>   that represent the first element (aka
>   as base index). The usual value is 0
>   or 1.
>
> ```
> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
> @IndexColumn(name = "drawer_position", base=1)
> public List<Drawer> getDrawers() {
>     return drawers;
> }
> ```

#### References

- Hibernate Annotations 3.4 Reference Guide

  - [2.4.6.2. Extra collection types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype) in the documentation.